# How do I make the checkbox works as multi select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a select option using checkbox. The select option works on click. So when I click on text "saloon" it gets clicked. How do I bring the onclick effect on the whole box instead of text only, and also, how do I bring hover effect on the box border?

I shall be looking for some help from the StackOverflow community.

Regards,
Bill

```js
  $(".vehicle-item").click(function(){
    var checkBoxes = $(this).siblings('input[type=checkbox]');
    checkBoxes.prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked') ? true : false);
    $(this).toggleClass("check-multiselect-vehicles");
  });
```

```css
 .items-collection .items {
     float: left;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}

 .items-collection .vehicle-item input[type=checkbox] {
     display: none;
}

 .items-collection label{
     padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
     float: left;
     margin:5px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     color: #6f7c87;
     border: 2px solid #b4bbc6;
     width: 65px;
     transition: all 225ms;
     display: block;
}

 .vehicle-item-title{
     font-size:11px;
}
 .vehicle-item:hover {
     color: #262959;
}

 .check-multiselect-vehicles {
     color: red;
}
 .saloon-icon, .suv-icon, .mini-icon {
     display: block;
     fill: #6F7C87;
     width: 60px;
     height: 28px;
     zoom: 1px;
}
 .saloon-icon:hover, .suv-icon:hover, .mini-icon:hover {
     fill: #262959;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-collection">
<div class="col-md-4 items car-col-responsive">
                                 <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                                    <label class="btn">
                                       <div class="vehicle-item">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="multi[]">
                                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 23" width="82%" height="100%" fill="#707D86">
                                          <g>
                                             <circle cx="37.5" cy="15.8" r="2.6"/>
                                             <circle cx="7.9" cy="15.9" r="2.7"/>
                                             <path d="M41.7,16.5c0,0,4.6,1.4,5.7-1.1c0,0,1.1-3.4-0.5-4.2l-0.1-1L45.6,10c0,0,0.9-1.9,0.2-2l-4.1-0.7L33.7,4c0,0-8.1-1.3-11.2,0c0,0-5.5,1.9-8.2,4.1c0,0-9.6,0.4-10.6,1.8c0,0-3.3,3.1-2.5,5c0,0,0.4,1.6,2,2.1H4c0,0-0.2-4.7,4.4-4.3c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.4,0,3.7,0.2,3.7,4.8h21.1c0,0,0.3-4.9,3.8-4.9C37.1,12.4,41.2,11.6,41.7,16.5z"/>
                                             <path d="M37.5,8.1h-9.7V4.5c0,0,6,0.1,6.7,0.6C34.6,5.1,36.8,6.3,37.5,8.1z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                             <path d="M25.8,4.4v3.6h-7.5C18.3,8.1,21.4,3.9,25.8,4.4z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                          </g>
                                          <path d="M4.2,10.1l0.6,0.9l-2,2.3l-1.5,0.5C1.3,13.7,2.5,10.2,4.2,10.1z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                          </svg>
                                          <h5 class="vehicle-item-title">Saloon</h5>
                                       </div>
                                    </label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                          <!-- SUVs -->
                          <div class="items col-md-4 car-col-responsive">
                             <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                                <label class="btn">
                                   <div class="vehicle-item">
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="multi[]">
                                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53 23" width="87%" height="100%" fill="#707D86">
                                      <g>
                                         <path d="M37.8,20.6H15.7l-1-0.8c0,0,0-4.5-3.5-4.4c0,0-4-0.6-4.1,4.2c0,0,0.2,1.2-1.4,1c0,0-1.8-0.3-2.5-1.6L2,17.4c0,0-0.6-2,0.6-2.5c0,0-1.5-2.1,2.5-3.3c0,0,3.7-1.6,5.8-1.3l11-5.8c0,0,15.3-2.2,23.7,0c0,0,3.7,1.9,4.6,7.6c0,0,0.4,5.8,0,7c0,0-0.7,1.5-1,1.6c0,0-1.1,0.7-2.2,0c0,0-0.5-5.4-4.8-5.1C42.3,15.5,38.1,14.9,37.8,20.6z"/>
                                         <path d="M41.8,7.2v4.5h4C45.8,11.7,45.4,8.3,41.8,7.2z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <path d="M31.1,6.4L29.9,11l9.2,0.2c0,0,1.3-4.3-1.4-4.8H31.1z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <path d="M27.8,6.4l-0.5,4.8l-8.5,0.1c0,0-1.1-1.7,0.6-2.9l4-1.8L27.8,6.4z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <circle cx="41.8" cy="20" r="3" fill="#707D86"/>
                                         <circle cx="10.7" cy="19.4" r="3" fill="#707D86"/>
                                         <path d="M5,12.2c0,0-3.7,0.9-2.5,3.3s3.2-0.7,3.2-0.7"/ fill="#FFFFFF">
                                      </g>
                                      </svg>
                                     <h5 class="vehicle-item-title">SUVs</h5>
                                   </div>
                                </label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It isn't working because the whole item is wrapped in a `label`; therefore a click anywhere in the box is toggling the checkbox, and then it's toggling again in javascript. The `label` solution works fine, except for your additional css markup, so a simple solution is to only use javascript to toggle the class when the checkbox's value is changed, and let the markup semantics handle whether or not the checkbox is clicked.

Edit: updated per your comment on desiring to change the background color. The only change was to target the `.btn` (`label`) element instead of the `.vehicle-item` to toggle the class, and move the `margin` outside that element.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  $(this).closest('.btn').toggleClass("check-multiselect-vehicles");
})
```

```css
.items-collection .items {
     float: left;
     padding: 0px;
     margin:5px;
}

 .items-collection .vehicle-item input[type=checkbox] {
     display: none;
}

 .items-collection label{
     padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
     float: left;
     border-radius: 3px;
     color: #6f7c87;
     border: 2px solid #b4bbc6;
     width: 65px;
     transition: all 225ms;
     display: block;
}

 .vehicle-item-title{
     font-size:11px;
}
 .vehicle-item:hover {
     color: #262959;
}

 .check-multiselect-vehicles {
     background: red;
}
 .saloon-icon, .suv-icon, .mini-icon {
     display: block;
     fill: #6F7C87;
     width: 60px;
     height: 28px;
     zoom: 1px;
}
 .saloon-icon:hover, .suv-icon:hover, .mini-icon:hover {
     fill: #262959;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-collection">
<div class="col-md-4 items car-col-responsive">
                                 <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                                    <label class="btn">
                                       <div class="vehicle-item">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="multi[]">
                                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 23" width="82%" height="100%" fill="#707D86">
                                          <g>
                                             <circle cx="37.5" cy="15.8" r="2.6"/>
                                             <circle cx="7.9" cy="15.9" r="2.7"/>
                                             <path d="M41.7,16.5c0,0,4.6,1.4,5.7-1.1c0,0,1.1-3.4-0.5-4.2l-0.1-1L45.6,10c0,0,0.9-1.9,0.2-2l-4.1-0.7L33.7,4c0,0-8.1-1.3-11.2,0c0,0-5.5,1.9-8.2,4.1c0,0-9.6,0.4-10.6,1.8c0,0-3.3,3.1-2.5,5c0,0,0.4,1.6,2,2.1H4c0,0-0.2-4.7,4.4-4.3c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.4,0,3.7,0.2,3.7,4.8h21.1c0,0,0.3-4.9,3.8-4.9C37.1,12.4,41.2,11.6,41.7,16.5z"/>
                                             <path d="M37.5,8.1h-9.7V4.5c0,0,6,0.1,6.7,0.6C34.6,5.1,36.8,6.3,37.5,8.1z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                             <path d="M25.8,4.4v3.6h-7.5C18.3,8.1,21.4,3.9,25.8,4.4z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                          </g>
                                          <path d="M4.2,10.1l0.6,0.9l-2,2.3l-1.5,0.5C1.3,13.7,2.5,10.2,4.2,10.1z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                          </svg>
                                          <h5 class="vehicle-item-title">Saloon</h5>
                                       </div>
                                    </label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                          <!-- SUVs -->
                          <div class="items col-md-4 car-col-responsive">
                             <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                                <label class="btn">
                                   <div class="vehicle-item">
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="multi[]">
                                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53 23" width="87%" height="100%" fill="#707D86">
                                      <g>
                                         <path d="M37.8,20.6H15.7l-1-0.8c0,0,0-4.5-3.5-4.4c0,0-4-0.6-4.1,4.2c0,0,0.2,1.2-1.4,1c0,0-1.8-0.3-2.5-1.6L2,17.4c0,0-0.6-2,0.6-2.5c0,0-1.5-2.1,2.5-3.3c0,0,3.7-1.6,5.8-1.3l11-5.8c0,0,15.3-2.2,23.7,0c0,0,3.7,1.9,4.6,7.6c0,0,0.4,5.8,0,7c0,0-0.7,1.5-1,1.6c0,0-1.1,0.7-2.2,0c0,0-0.5-5.4-4.8-5.1C42.3,15.5,38.1,14.9,37.8,20.6z"/>
                                         <path d="M41.8,7.2v4.5h4C45.8,11.7,45.4,8.3,41.8,7.2z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <path d="M31.1,6.4L29.9,11l9.2,0.2c0,0,1.3-4.3-1.4-4.8H31.1z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <path d="M27.8,6.4l-0.5,4.8l-8.5,0.1c0,0-1.1-1.7,0.6-2.9l4-1.8L27.8,6.4z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <circle cx="41.8" cy="20" r="3" fill="#707D86"/>
                                         <circle cx="10.7" cy="19.4" r="3" fill="#707D86"/>
                                         <path d="M5,12.2c0,0-3.7,0.9-2.5,3.3s3.2-0.7,3.2-0.7"/ fill="#FFFFFF">
                                      </g>
                                      </svg>
                                     <h5 class="vehicle-item-title">SUVs</h5>
                                   </div>
                                </label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                            </div>
```

Edit: this second solution is more difficult given your comment that you're trying to change the background color.
Note that you could also remove javascript completely using the css `:checked` pseudo-selector and the general sibling selector:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .vehicle-item-title {
  color: red;
}
```

```css
.items-collection .items {
     float: left;
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
}

 .items-collection .vehicle-item input[type=checkbox] {
     display: none;
}

 .items-collection label{
     padding: 6px 0px 0px 0px;
     float: left;
     margin:5px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     color: #6f7c87;
     border: 2px solid #b4bbc6;
     width: 65px;
     transition: all 225ms;
     display: block;
}

 .vehicle-item-title{
     font-size:11px;
}
 .vehicle-item:hover {
     color: #262959;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .vehicle-item-title {
     color: red;
}
 .saloon-icon, .suv-icon, .mini-icon {
     display: block;
     fill: #6F7C87;
     width: 60px;
     height: 28px;
     zoom: 1px;
}
 .saloon-icon:hover, .suv-icon:hover, .mini-icon:hover {
     fill: #262959;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-collection">
<div class="col-md-4 items car-col-responsive">
                                 <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                                    <label class="btn">
                                       <div class="vehicle-item">
                                          <input type="checkbox" name="multi[]">
                                          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 23" width="82%" height="100%" fill="#707D86">
                                          <g>
                                             <circle cx="37.5" cy="15.8" r="2.6"/>
                                             <circle cx="7.9" cy="15.9" r="2.7"/>
                                             <path d="M41.7,16.5c0,0,4.6,1.4,5.7-1.1c0,0,1.1-3.4-0.5-4.2l-0.1-1L45.6,10c0,0,0.9-1.9,0.2-2l-4.1-0.7L33.7,4c0,0-8.1-1.3-11.2,0c0,0-5.5,1.9-8.2,4.1c0,0-9.6,0.4-10.6,1.8c0,0-3.3,3.1-2.5,5c0,0,0.4,1.6,2,2.1H4c0,0-0.2-4.7,4.4-4.3c0,0,0,0,0.1,0c0.4,0,3.7,0.2,3.7,4.8h21.1c0,0,0.3-4.9,3.8-4.9C37.1,12.4,41.2,11.6,41.7,16.5z"/>
                                             <path d="M37.5,8.1h-9.7V4.5c0,0,6,0.1,6.7,0.6C34.6,5.1,36.8,6.3,37.5,8.1z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                             <path d="M25.8,4.4v3.6h-7.5C18.3,8.1,21.4,3.9,25.8,4.4z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                          </g>
                                          <path d="M4.2,10.1l0.6,0.9l-2,2.3l-1.5,0.5C1.3,13.7,2.5,10.2,4.2,10.1z" fill="#FFFDFD"/>
                                          </svg>
                                          <h5 class="vehicle-item-title">Saloon</h5>
                                       </div>
                                    </label>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                          <!-- SUVs -->
                          <div class="items col-md-4 car-col-responsive">
                             <div data-toggle="buttons" class="btn-group">
                                <label class="btn">
                                   <div class="vehicle-item">
                                      <input type="checkbox" name="multi[]">
                                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 53 23" width="87%" height="100%" fill="#707D86">
                                      <g>
                                         <path d="M37.8,20.6H15.7l-1-0.8c0,0,0-4.5-3.5-4.4c0,0-4-0.6-4.1,4.2c0,0,0.2,1.2-1.4,1c0,0-1.8-0.3-2.5-1.6L2,17.4c0,0-0.6-2,0.6-2.5c0,0-1.5-2.1,2.5-3.3c0,0,3.7-1.6,5.8-1.3l11-5.8c0,0,15.3-2.2,23.7,0c0,0,3.7,1.9,4.6,7.6c0,0,0.4,5.8,0,7c0,0-0.7,1.5-1,1.6c0,0-1.1,0.7-2.2,0c0,0-0.5-5.4-4.8-5.1C42.3,15.5,38.1,14.9,37.8,20.6z"/>
                                         <path d="M41.8,7.2v4.5h4C45.8,11.7,45.4,8.3,41.8,7.2z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <path d="M31.1,6.4L29.9,11l9.2,0.2c0,0,1.3-4.3-1.4-4.8H31.1z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <path d="M27.8,6.4l-0.5,4.8l-8.5,0.1c0,0-1.1-1.7,0.6-2.9l4-1.8L27.8,6.4z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                                         <circle cx="41.8" cy="20" r="3" fill="#707D86"/>
                                         <circle cx="10.7" cy="19.4" r="3" fill="#707D86"/>
                                         <path d="M5,12.2c0,0-3.7,0.9-2.5,3.3s3.2-0.7,3.2-0.7"/ fill="#FFFFFF">
                                      </g>
                                      </svg>
                                     <h5 class="vehicle-item-title">SUVs</h5>
                                   </div>
                                </label>
                             </div>
                          </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. But I think the question is still not answered because the real concept was that onclick on the box the whole box becomes a checkbox. Because when I tried to add the background color to the box it only added the background color to the "Saloon" div and not the whole box. Example: http://prntscr.com/n37nzi. Any leads?

Comment: That's a different problem from the one in your question, but I've updated the first snippet to meet that requirement.